# How do I reply to a mail with in-line comments on iOS?

Tags: ios, email, ios-appstore, ms-office

When I answer emails from outlook on my PC I can add in-line answers to questions I’m asked and it automatically add my initials inside brackets when I click “enter” like so:

```
What is the weather today?
[RW] Sunny and bright
How do you feel today?
[RW] Very good, thank you!
```

It also makes my answers bold and italic usually.
Is there an iOS app that does the same?

Comment: Have you tried Outlook for ios?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn’t do the trick

Answer (score -1):

IOS support also what you need:

- from upper right icons of the received mail, press the curved to left arrow to generate a replay;
- press return on the line where you need to write an answer to create an empty new row;
- on your keyboard, upper right, touch/press the letters "B" and "I" to generate bold and italics. Please note these letters become color blue;
- type your answer. It will be written in bold italics;
- send as usual!

Comment: Does this automatically add the initials in front as requested?

Comment: I meant how to do that automatically like on outlook.